# JavaFX - Trying to create my own custom button class

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create Button class with specific styling.

```
public class RoundBTN extends Button{
    public RoundBTN(String name){
        Button roundButton = new Button(name);
        roundButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #20B2AA; -fx-background-radius: 15px; -fx-text-fill: #ffffff");
        getChildren().add(roundButton);
    }
}
```

Then when I go to my application class try to build a new button:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    StackPane layout = new StackPane();

    layout.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    layout.getChildren().add(new RoundBTN("test"));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout,200,200));
    stage.show();
}
```

When I run the program I get an empty normal button with no styling.

Sorry for the noob question, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `Button` in the constructor of class `RoundBTN`. This does not change `RoundBTN` at all.

The first thing you need to do in the constructor of class `RoundBTN` is to call the superclass constructor. Then you do not create a new `Button` but rather just set the style.

```java
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class RoundBTN extends Button {
    public RoundBTN(String name){
        super(name);
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #20B2AA; -fx-background-radius: 15px; -fx-text-fill: #ffffff");
    }
}
```

But if all you want to do is just change the styling, you don't need to extend class `Button`, just create a regular `Button` and set its styling.

```java
Button b = new Button("test");
b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #20B2AA; -fx-background-radius: 15px; -fx-text-fill: #ffffff");
```

Comment: Nice answer.  IMO for many applications, the preferred way to do this would be to use an external style sheet, as demonstrated in this [Oracle JavaFX CSS styling tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm).